# Laravel 5.2 + Modify default login Behavior + Throllting stopped working when cache driver Array is used

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I have created new project in Laravel 5.2 and tried to modify default behavior of Auth-Login.

Created new method called postLogin which is being called when login form is submitted.

Below is the code I have written to achieve login throttling in postRegister Method.

```
protected function postLogin(AuthLoginRequest $request){

    $credentials = $this->getCredentials($request);
    $credentials['is_activated'] = "Yes";

    $remember = $request->has('remember');

    $throttles = $this->isUsingThrottlesLoginsTrait();


    if ($throttles && $this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
        return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
    }

    if (Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->attempt($credentials, $remember)) {
        // add login in case of success
        return $this->handleUserWasAuthenticated($request, $throttles);
    } else {
        if ($throttles) {
            $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
        }

        return redirect("/login")
            ->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'))
            ->withErrors([
                $this->loginUsername() => $this->getFailedLoginMessage(),
            ]);
    }
}
```

this works fine when I keep cache driver to "file."
When I keep Cache Driver to "array", this code does not work.

Can someone please notify me what I am lacking in order to make this work when cache driver = "array"?

Comment: Are you getting any error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things you should note:

- The `array` driver simply stores any cached values in an internal array. The values are not retained between requests.
- If you check out the `ThrottlesLogins` trait, you can see it's incrementing a cache counter on every failed login.

And that's the reason its not working.

**From Laravel Documentation:**

*Note: The array driver is typically used for running tests to prevent session* data from persisting.